# QSerialPort and sending bytes (with value > 127?)

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have:

```
QString hex = "0234301c4c49541d4741546f77617220a5a91e42411e43311e44332c30301e45332c30301e47737a74756b613742413303";
QByteArray test = QByteArray::fromHex(hex.toLatin1());
```

Now, i want to send it over SerialPort:

```
serial = new QSerialPort(this);
serial->setPortName("ttyACM0");
serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

if(serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))

{

    qDebug()<<"Port is open!";
    if(serial->isWritable())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Yes, i can write to port!";
    }
    serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
    serial->write(test.data());
    serial->flush(); // Port Error 12 (timed out???)
    serial->close()
 }
```

I become no result (also char/byte values they are less than 127 seems to be send, but not those they are over this value)

My question -> how to convert this QByteArray to send all bytes corectly?
(i tried to found the answer in google, but without success / i'm newbie)

Comment: Are you using `signed char` or `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`?

Comment: where should i use unsigned char?  (in my program i should send datas value from 0 to 255)

Comment: Why do you do `serial->write(test.data());`? `QSerialPort::write()` has an overload that take directly a `QByteArray` so it should be enough to do `serial->write(test);`... Does it work this way?

Furthermore (not relevant for your problem): why you do `serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);` before writing data to the serial port? I think it does make more sense if you do that after having written data to the serial port (if you really need that), isn't it?

Comment: I agree, first do `serial->write(test);` then `serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1)`
and remove the `flush()`

Comment: The `signed char` type only allows 7 bits of data (assuming your platform has 8 bits for char), one bit reserved for the sign.  The `unsigned char` allows you to use all 8 bits (0 to 255) for data.  The `uint8_t` data type says you want a data type that is unsigned and 8 bits.  Remember that a `char` type can be `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`, *depending on the platform*.

Comment: I suggest using `uint8_t` as the data type that holds value.  For example, your array should be of `uint8_t`.

Comment: ok,  how to send uint8_t instead of QByteArray / how to convert those values?

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly do not want to be calling the QSerialPort write overload that takes a const char*. Look at the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-1) for that overload:

> Writes data from a zero-terminated string of 8-bit characters to the device.

But you are NOT writing a zero-terminated C-string, you're writing arbitrary binary data. So you need to call the write overload that takes a QByteArray directly, like this:

```
serial->write(test);
```

As stated in some of the other comments, the stuff about waitForBytesWritten before calling write doesn't make a lot of sense either, but your biggest issue is trying to treat your QByteArray of arbitrary data as a null-terminated C-String.

Comment: it doesn't wort at all.  if i send qbytearray with char(int) grater than 127 i become no echo answer from cash register and error 12...timed out?,  in other case i become recipient and echo confirmation (while port read)... something is wrong with this ::write function

Answer (score 0):

they was an error in crc code (downloaded from some web-portal)
it was cast to uint16_t instead uint8_t 
now it really works.
thank You for help!